# sharing the result of search in another component in angular 13

Tags: angular

I have a home component where you can find a search filter and I want display the result of this search in a table in a second component. how can I do it plz ?

note that the coponents are not child and parent component. thank you in advance

Comment: create a service to comunicate between components

Answer (score -1):

Make a service file
if both components are loaded at the same time
then use subjects in service files and pass data through them
if the second component loads after the search then you can use any of both simple variables or subjects.